# Complex integration over a contour

Tags: matlab, math, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

I know this is not exactly a programming question, but I've been trying to coax Matlab and Mathematica into solving this for me.  This is a question on a practice exam for a class in Complex Variables.  Any help, or direction to where i might find some, would be greatly appreciated.

[image: integral]

I've tried many different things, and I cant seem to figure it out...  WolframAlpha takes too long to compute it (even with Pro extended computation time).  Mathematica doesn't like it, and Matlab gives me some heinously disgusting expression...

Mathematica Code:

```
Integrate[(z^2 + 4)/(z^3 - 5), z, (2 - i), (2 + 2 i)]
```

Matlab Code:

```
int((z^2 + 4)/(z^3 - 5), z, (2 - i), (2 + 2*i))
```

Obviously, there is some kind of manipulation that should be done to this in order to simplify the calculation, but I'm just not sure where to start...
Can I just say that this integral is greater than the integral of `z^2/z^3 = 1/z` and then change the integration variable? I don't know, what do you guys think?

Again, I know it's not exactly programming, but I've found people on this site are the smartest around and thought I might give it a shot.

Comment: First, the imaginary `i` in *Mathematica* is `I`. And integration limits should be in form: {z, from, to}. So *Mathematica* code to calculate is: `N[Abs[Integrate[(z^2 + 4)/(z^3 - 5), {z, 2 - I, 2 + 2 I}]]]`.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to evaluate the integral to prove the inequality. I even think this is not requested. Maybe they can help you at Math.SO?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as OP admits and as the answers illustrate, it's not really about programming.

Comment: If you can't get Matlab to solve complex integrals for you symbolically, you can code it in R2 and solve numerically. That's something to keep in mind. Otherwise, yes, homework math questions go to Math.SE. You can also try asking an integration specific question instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Integration by hand

If you wish to integrate it by hand I would recommend a [partial fraction expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction) to turn the fraction into easier to integrate parts.

### Approximate Integration

Consider the absolute value of z.

z goes from 2-i to 2+2i so its absolute value will be between 2 (when it is at 2+0i) and sqrt(8) (when it is at 2+2i).

This means:

- 4<=|z^2|<=8
- the absolute value z^2+4 will always be <= 12
- and the absolute value of z^3-5 will always be >= 3

Combining these two we can deduce that the absolute value of the integrand will always be <= 12/3.

This lets us conclude that the absolute value of the integral must be <= 12 (because the line is of length 3).

Answer (score 1):

Note that, plotted in the complex plane, the contour is the vertical line from (2,-1) to (2,2). That said, in Mathematica you can write the integral as:

```
z = x + I y;
x = 2;
int = Integrate[ ((z^2 + 4)/(z^3 - 5), {y,-1,2}];
N@Abs@int
(* Out[]:= 2.08808 *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, that you need to use `I` for the imaginary number in Mathematica. This results is, in fact, less than 12:

```
N@Abs@% <= 12
(* Out[]:= True *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Better use the ML theorem (triangle inequality for countour).  The integral is less than M, the max of the modulus of f(z) along the contour, times L the length of the path.  The path is a straight line of length 3 as can been seen in the complex plane.  The maximum modulus is 2 x sqrt(2) (from the origin to 2+2i, and the minimum modulus is sqrt(5), from the origin to 2-i.  M is easily calculated by majoring the numerator and minoring the denominator of the modulus of f(z) and ends up less than 12 (because 5 x sqrt(5) is above 8).
So the problem is solved without calculating the integral.